# Transfer music files from PC running WinXP to Samsung Galaxy S6

Tags: windows, file-transfer, samsung-galaxy-s-6

Android n00b, here.  I finally got my PC to see the folder structure of my S6, but it won't allow me to paste files onto it.  When I go into the Music folder and right-click, the word "Paste" is grayed out.  When I try to drag-n-drop, it won't even let me hover over the S6 peripheral.

I'm doing all this via Windows Explorer, running on a machine with WinXP SP3.  Can someone tell me how to get my MP3's onto my S6?

Comment: Do you have Windows Media Player 10 or even better 11? I would highly recommend not using Windows XP at all (discontinued, no support for modern technologies etc.). What format are those music files?

Comment: What about using Kies?

Comment: Are you using the latest Google recommended MTP driver for WinXP?

Comment: @Giant, the files are MP3s please read the question.